# How to get other functions in an Angular service to await a resolve of a promise

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-promise, angular-services

so I'm trying my hand at building a site based on Angular and I've toyed with Angular before but never anything to this level and I'm running aground a little in the entire complex matter that is / are promises and observables.

So to give a bit of context, I'm using the Contentful app and using the lovely NPM JS package they provide. Makes stuff heaps easier than having to write my own HTTP class.

I wrote a beautiful service for consuming this package and it retrieves and parses all the data, no problem. At least no problem untl I try to have multiple different functions parse the already parsed data...if that makes sense.

### Current application flow

So what I currently have is basically the following set up:
1. Service gets injected into component
2. Component's NgOnInit function calls a public function in the service 
3. That function calls upon the contentful NPM package to do a request for all the data I need. 
4. Contentful's NPM package returns a Promise
5. As soon as the promise resolves an anonymous arrow function runs the returned data through some filters, dumps them into a tree structure of "models" and returns this tree. 
6. This tree gets assigned to a private "store" variable in the service
7. Execution then gets returned to my NgOnInit in the component that then triggers another function in the component
8. That function then calls a different function in the service that needs to do processing on the store variable

This is where I get stuck. I've got the NgOnInit and API query function both running async/await and that works fine, I get my content back no worries. But I'd rather not define every function as async and using await everytime. That doesn't seem like it should be a thing.

I've tried googling this, but I don't get many helpful results for Angular4 (or even 2)+. Now it's fully possible I just don't know what to Google for, but I don't even know what I should search for.

I'm trying to think of different solutions myself, but everything I come up with can and will work, something less pretty than other, but it all comes back to "you're gonna have to use async|await".

### My question

Is there any way to perform operations on my store variable from a function that is not running async/await?

```
// Service class
export class ContentService {
    private _store;

    // API consumer
    public async queryEndpoint() {
        if (this._store === null) {
            this._store = await this._client.getEntries().then((d) => {
                console.log(d); // Works! shows the content from the API
            });
        }
        return await this._store;
    }

    // Gets triggered from the component
    public doMoreProcessing() {
        // If I console.log(this._store) I get a ZoneAwarePromise back
        return this._store;
    }
}

// Component
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _contentService: ContentService) {} // inject the ContentService

    async ngOnInit() {
        console.log(await this._contentService.queryEndpoint()); // Works! shows content from API
        this.doComponentStuff();
    }

    public doComponentStuff(){
        console.log(this._contentService.doMoreProcessing()) // ZoneAwarePromise :(
    }

}
```

I know I can make it work by putting async|await everywhere, but that seems...suboptimal... so I'd gladly here if there's any pro's out there that can tell me how I can get my data back in doComponentStuff and doMoreProcessing instead of a zoneawarepromise.

Comment: Is `this._store` meant to be a promise? You are awaiting AND using a `Promise.then` on `this._client.getEntries();`. Just use await on `getEntries()` and console.log(this._store) the next line to get the same result as your `then()` logic.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to perform operations on my store variable from a function that is not running async/await?

Yes, `getEntries().then()` returns a Promise and gets assigned to `this._store`. Try the following code so you don't have to `async`/`await` on all methods that need that cached data.

```
// Service class
export class ContentService {
    private _store;

    // API consumer
    public async queryEndpoint() {
        if (this._store === null) {
            this._store = await this._client.getEntries();
            console.log(this._store);
        }
        return this._store;
    }

    public doMoreProcessing() {
        return this._store;
    }
}

// Component
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _contentService: ContentService) {}

    async ngOnInit() {
        console.log(await this._contentService.queryEndpoint()); // Works! shows content from API
        this.doComponentStuff();
    }

    public doComponentStuff(){
        console.log(this._contentService.doMoreProcessing()) // Works! shows cached content from API
    }
}
```